# fql like count limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, limit, facebook-fql, restriction

Is there same restriction to use FQL to get likes count for some urls?

```
SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url in ("site.com/page1.html","site.com/page2.html")
```

I want to get an likes count **for thousends** of urls in my domain. I will run it from cron script in every night (server is in Europe), but I'm afraid that facebook will ban my ip/server after such us mass request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP Get command has a max limit length that might get in your way before Facebook might.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fastsharepoint/thread/b193fc10-3c39-43d3-9e4a-378ff90125f2

Comment: Yes. Thanks for paying attention at this problem. But this is very easy to get solutions - in loop check only a few urls.
Sorry, but I'm still worried that Facebook can ban me after mass request :/

Comment: You may want to research into what facebook calls Insights.  This might offer some way to view multiple pages at a time.

Comment: Also, you may want to have your company's business development group contact Facebook to see if they would be able to work out an agreement.